# Angular sub-component style does not change until next ngAfterViewChecked

Tags: javascript, angular

Angular version: 5.0.3

I have put my code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ddhyxx).

I have made a custom inkbar module, and imported it to the app. I use

```
<lib-inkbar [nextEle]="inkbarSubject" [color]="inkbarColor"></lib-inkbar>
```

...to install it in my `app.component`.

The inkbar under the navigation menu tabs is expected to automatically go in position where router link is currently active. (And this is done by getting the width and offset left of a given element, and move to it.) For example, at the beginning, "/index" is active, so "Index" tab has a class "active", and inkbar should translate under it.

I have achieved this by putting the code in Angular's `ngAfterViewChecked` life-cycle. `inkbarMove()` tells inkbar where to go by telling it the element (i.e. the active nav tab).

```
ngAfterViewChecked() {
  this.navMenus = this.ul.nativeElement.children;
  let actMenu = this.getAvtiveMenu();
  if (actMenu) {
    this.inkbarMove(actMenu);
  }
}

inkbarMove = (ele: HTMLBaseElement | MouseEvent) => {
  if (ele instanceof MouseEvent) {
    ele = ele.target as HTMLBaseElement;
  }
  this.inkbarSubject.next(ele);
};
```

However, this works only after next `ngAfterViewChecked()` fires. When page **first loads**, the inkbar will stay `{width: 0px; left: 0px}` style, as initial default value, no matter how many times I tell it to "Move" (I even wrote a for-loop, which made my browser crash, but still didn't work lol). It will only starts to move after I press the **button** and manually call `ngAfterViewChecked()` again.

Does someone know what is going on here?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-frhqku?file=modules/inkbar/inkbar.component.ts

Comment: Actually, works good for me event for first load. If it doesn't on your machine - you can try also ngAfterViewInit.